# Prove that the rate of convergence of a sequence is unique

Tags: numerical-methods

I know that the rate of convergence of a sequence is unique. But I do not know why. Please prove that the rate of convergence of a sequence is unique.

[Rate of Convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence)

[image: Rate of Convergence Definition]

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help rather than downvotes and votes to close if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know how to prove that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "rate of convergence of a sequence"? We need to know what that is before we can prove anything about it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate_of_convergence

Comment: There is more than one definition of order of convergence in the Wikipedia article and they describe different concepts. You should at least copy the definition that you are using.

Comment: You are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $e_n > 0$ and $e_n \rightarrow 0$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let us assume that the order of convergence is both $p_1\geq1$ and $p_2 \geq 1$. We have to show that $p_1 = p_2$. By assumption we have
$$ \frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n^{p_i}} \rightarrow c_i > 0, \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.$$
Without loss of generality, we have $p_1 < p_2$. If $p_1 = 1$, then the demand is $c_1 \in (0,1)$, but this will not be important here.

It follows that
$$ \frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n^{p_1}} = \frac{e_{n+1}}{e_n^{p_2}} e_n^{p_2 - p_1} \rightarrow c_2 \cdot 0 = 0, \quad n \rightarrow \infty, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$
because $p_2 - p_1>0$ and $e_n$ tends to zero. This shows that the order is not $p_1$. We have a contradiction. Hence $p_1 = p_2$.

Comment: @bezi The order is ultimately more significant than than rate, unless the order is $1$, in which case a small rate ensures faster convergence. In my native language (Danish), "rate" is valid word with connotations that very close to speed which in our setting is closely tied to order. It requires an effort for me to distinguish between the terms "rate" and "order". Since the rate is literally a limit, it did not even occur to me that you meant anything but "order".

Comment: I have actually find in some cases that rates can have a rather significant contribution as well as the order. This is particularly the case when dealing with bracketing methods, where one endpoint stalls. In this situation, the rate is usually proportional to how close this stalled point is to the root, which for single or double precision may have a significant impact.